# Abrir popup quando estiver em link específico

Tags: javascript

Tenho que abrir um popup em um página específica.

Meu JS está assim:

```
if($('.popup-banner').length > 0) {
    $('.popup-banner .fechar, .popup-banner .link-fechar, .popup-overlay').click(function() {
        $('.popup-overlay, .popup-banner').fadeOut(300);
    });
}
```

No momento, está abrindo em qualquer página que eu acesse. Mas, eu quero abrir somente quando estiver na home, o endereço inicial da home é www.teste.com.br

Comment: Felipe, creio que, se você quer que o comportamento só dispare na página inicial, você poderia usar `if (window.location.href === '/')` na linha dois, antes de ligar a função click no elemento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer tanto com `window.location.href` e verificar a URL, por exemplo:

```
if ( !!location.href.match("https?:\/\/pt.stackoverflow.com\/?$") ) {
    alert("Página inicial")
}
```

Ou você pode fazer com `window.location.pathname` e verificar o *path* da URL, por exemplo:

```
if ( !!window.location.pathname.match("(?:\/|index\.(?:php|asp|html?))$") ) {
    alert("Página inicial")
}
```

**Explicação do Regex 1:**

```
https?:\/\/pt.stackoverflow.com\/?$
   └┬┘                         └─┬─┘
    │                            └──── Informa que a URL tem que terminar com `/`. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
    └───────────────────────────────── Informa que o `s` como opcional. Isso serve tanto para http://, quanto https://
```

**Explicação do Regex 2:**

```
(?:\/|index\.(?:php|asp|html?))$
 └┬┘ └───────────┬──────────┘
  │              │             
  │              │            
  │              └──────────────── ou terminar com index.php; index.asp; index.html; ou index.htm
  └─────────────────────────────── Informa que o `path` deve terminar com `/`
```

> O `!!` serve para converter o resultado em booleano.

Se você quiser algo bem mais simples, pode utilizar o `slice`, por exemplo:

```
if (location.pathname.slice(-1) === "/") {
    alert("Página Inicial");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma é pegar a variável `location.href` (URL atual) e remover `www.`, `http://`, `https://` e barra `/`. Se o resultado for apenas `teste.com.br`, você está na página inicial:

```js
var url_ = "http://www.teste.com.br/"; // apenas para teste. Apague esta linha
//var url_ = location.href; // descomente esta linha
url_ = url_.replace(/www.|https|http|:|\//g,"");

if($('.popup-banner').length > 0 && url_ == "teste.com.br") {
   
   $("div").show(); // apenas para exemplo. Apague esta linha
   
    $('.popup-banner .fechar, .popup-banner .link-fechar, .popup-overlay').click(function() {
        $('.popup-overlay, .popup-banner').fadeOut(300);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup-banner" style="display: none;">popup página inicial</div>
```